# Memory Leak Example -references and objects

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

I have the below method.Suppose i call `A.m1()` 10,000 times from class `B`.
So all 10,000 `MyObj`  objects will be garbage collected as their scope is only within the `m1()` method.
There is no memory leak?

```java
class A {
    String m1() {
        MyObj obj = new Mybj();
    }
}
```

And i call it below

```java
class B {
    void m2() {
        String s = classAObj.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create code examples that compile. `m1` needs to return a `String`. But regarding your question: In `m1`, `obj` goes out of scope as soon as `m1` returns at which point the object it references is eligible for garbage collection. So there is no memory leak no matter how many times it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The references created in the method are eventually garbage collected when they go out of scope.  But it doesn't necessary happen immediately.

Here is a demo that shows that the references are collected.  But first
some terms.

- hard reference - A normal reference to an object that will be around 
  until it is garbage collected.  These are the typical instance values resulting
   from object creation.
- weak references - references that point to the same object as a hard reference.
    When a hard reference is garbage collected, the associated weak references are also collected.

How this works.

- The method `m1` is called `n` times, each time creating a weak reference of an instance of `A` and returning it.
- This is then added to a list.
- Once the hard references are garbage collected, the weak references that refer to the same objects will also be collected
- The weak reference will then return null when trying to retrieve its associated
   object.

```
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GarbageCollection {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get out of static context
        new GarbageCollection().start();
    }
    public void start() {
        
        int n = 10_000;
        List<WeakReference<A>> weak = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create `n` weak references of `A` by calling `m1` and returning the reference.
Then it add to the `List`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            WeakReference<A> wk = m1();
            weak.add(wk);
        }
```

Now iterate thru the List of weak references to see how many are null.
Zero is expected
 since the garbage collector has not yet run. All of those `A` allocations created in `m1` are still lurking around in the heap.

```
        int count = 0;
        for (WeakReference<A> wk : weak) {
            if (wk.get() == null) {
                count++;
            }
        }
       
        System.out.println(count); // probably zero
```

Now repeat the same process but explicitly invoke the garbage collector.

```
        count = 0;
        System.gc();
        for (WeakReference<A> wk : weak) {
            if (wk.get() == null) {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

At this point, count should be non-zero (or possibly `n` for small values of `n`) to
 show some or all of the objects have been collected.

```
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    
    public WeakReference<A> m1() {
       A a = new A();
       return new WeakReference<>(a);
    }
}

class A {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a C++ background. In Java, it's quite hard to get a memory leak because of its garbage collection system. Garbage collection can get complicated, but the basic idea is there is a program constantly running in the background looking in the heap for an unused object, and when it finds one, it deletes it. So when you exit the `m1()` method, there are no references to the new `Mybj()` object so the garbage collector deletes it.

Comment: my point is MyObj() garbage collected if  s still has refernce to it.No right i guess